Ways to alleviate my CFL restriction?
I have an advection problem with a sever time stepping restriction. I am using explicit RK type time stepping schemes and standard finite difference so everything is matrix free. Other than going for an implicit scheme, are there some purely numerical schemes I can look into to alleviate my time stepping restriction and perhaps accelerate my time to solution?

Can you give some more details on your problem? Is it linear/nonlinear, size of the discretized system, etc. For example, if you have a linear problem with very large eigenvalues, there might not be much you can do to improve explicit time-stepping

Yeah I think I got my answer

For strictly hyperbolic PDEs your options are somewhat limited. The best you usually can do is pick a different RK method which has a higher effective CFL per stage. If you have something mixed hyperbolic/parabolic and its the parabolic part which is causing problems you can try Runge-Kutta-Chebychev methods.

There are also mixed implicit-explicit time stepping methods where you solve the stiff parts implicitly and everything else explicitly, but this might not be what you're looking for and it's by no means a panacea.
